# Redefining an environment or a command with an indefinite numbers of items

Tags: lists, environments

According to LaTeX's basic commands if I want to create a list of items I have to use the following concept code:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{itemize}
```

To keep my code as clean as possible and really customizable I use another concept:

```
\begin{myenv}
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{myenv}
```

If it's possible, I'd like to also customize the "item command" like this (but it's not really essential):

```
\begin{myenv}
  \myitem first
  \myitem second
  \myitem third
\end{myenv}
```

The problem is: How I can redefine an environment like this?

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
  {?}
  {?}
```

I'd like to ask the same question for the newly created command with

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}{?}
```

Comment: Will `\myitem` have an optional argument as the standard `\item`?

Comment: @gonzalo-medina yes, i'd like to create my own tags to keep the code simple and customizable, but i don't want to lose any features.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `enumitem` package to set up your own list.

Note that in the code below I have used `\newlist` to create the environment `mylist` and `setlist` to customize it. The `{10}` refers to the `max-depth`, which means that you could have at most 10 nested versions you are likely to have.

The `enumitem` package provides *many* more options for customizing the labels, indentation, margins, font, etc- see the documentation for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[mylist]{label=$\triangleright$}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    \item my first item
    \item my second item
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So it's not possible to define a new itemlist in a new environment, have to use the \newlist command, but what about a new command with an indefinite list of arguments? For example i like to create a command to set all text to a monospaced font <code> \newcommand{\cmd}[?]{\texttt{#?}} <\code>

Comment: I think the `keyval` package might be useful to you

Comment: When it could be possible i will give it a look, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Defining a new environment that matches the `itemize` environment is done in the following way:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}%
  {\begin{itemize}}% \begin{myenv}
  {\end{itemize}}% \end{myenv}
```

Defining a command that does something similar to `\item` is done in the following way:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\LetLtxMacro{\mycmd}{\item}% \mycmd = \item
```

Note that `\item` may take an optional argument, and it is therefore not as easy to merely "copy" it through `\newcommand{\mycmd}{\item}`. The [`letltxmacro` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) allows for making a "responsible" copy. Here is a minimal example that shows the usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myenv}%
  {\begin{itemize}}% \begin{myenv}
  {\end{itemize}}% \end{myenv}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\LetLtxMacro{\mycmd}{\item}% \mycmd = \item
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
  \mycmd first
  \mycmd second
  \mycmd third
\end{myenv}
​\end{document}​​​​​​
```

As mentioned above, you can now also use `\mycmd[<stuff>]` which will override the traditional `\textbullet` itemized bullet.

Comment: Actually `\item` is *not* defined to have an optional argument, but in doubt it's better to use `\LetLtxMacro`. One can check with Martin Scharrer's `texdef` script: `texdef -t latex item` will answer `macro:->...` which means that it has no argument.